# How can I get the document ID of a file in OneDrive for Business without visiting the Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

I have a team site synced to my laptop with OneDrive for Business.
How can I get the Document ID of a file via Windows Explorer without looking the file up on the SharePoint site? A method involving the command line is also fine as I can script that into a keyboard shortcut.

I have tried the "Share -> Copy Link" context menu, but this gives me an absolute URL.

I have looked in the Windows Explorer document properties, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, there is no way to get the Document ID of a file via Windows Explorer. And in the Windows Explorer document properties, it doesn's display SharePoint properties.

We have to go to the SharePoint Site and check the Document ID of the file.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have expanded my question to also include any other methods besides visiting the Sharepoint site. Do you maybe have any suggestions there?

Answer (score 1):

It is not feasible to display the properties of file that located in SharePoint in the Windows Explorer.

The mechanism of storing the properties works differently in SharePoint and Windows. The related columns won't be available to Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have expanded my question to also include any other methods besides visiting the Sharepoint site. Do you maybe have any suggestions there?